# ok I've made a plain api of google translate

Tags: php, google-translate

I just need a way to use it in php it uses url params here is what I mean

```
<?php
$url = "http://raizen.tk/translate/?lang=".$_POST['lang']."&term=".$_POST['term'].;
$html = iconv("gb2312","utf-8",$html);
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "utf-8" );
$e = curl_exec($ch);
echo $e;
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

my vps does not show php errors so i do not know why it wont work when i add the  html can anyone help if you can then I would be so happy and that would mean google api would be free again :)

Comment: what? firstly, have you tried adding `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your php page to output any php errors? As for the rest of the question I have no idea what you're asking; please clarify, with examples if possible.

Comment: I'm using curl to grab whats been translated but what i was tring to do was use $_post[] and a form to add the params when user inputs like you see here http://raizen.tk/translate/translatef/

Comment: but it keeps going blank when it goes to the translate.php

Comment: the translate page seems to work fine (eg [http://raizen.tk/translate/?lang=es&term=hello](http://raizen.tk/translate/?lang=es&term=hello)), there looks like there's an error in the above code, I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = "http://raizen.tk/translate/?lang=".$_POST['lang']."&term=".$_POST['term'].;
```

has an extra `.` at the end of the line before the semicolon. Try this:

```
$url = "http://raizen.tk/translate/?lang=".$_POST['lang']."&term=".$_POST['term'];
```

Comment: still does not display and i just fixed it to translate any langauge to any langauge ;(

Comment: well other than i need to get it to output in utf-8

Comment: maybe is because of the api its self im going to rework that it may not be displaying do to the fact if the params are blank it redirects to /translate/500.html

Comment: the code you've pasted in your question works fine for me if I remove the last `.` as mentioned in my answer, so I think the issue may be with your server config or elsewhere in the script?

Comment: :o you maybe right but as soon as i figure out whats wrong I'm going to release it

Comment: ok i ran the script on another server well webhost it gave this 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'curl_close' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /home/u126144914/public_html/php_files/translate.php on line 13

Comment: and i fixed it i put the echo $e before the curl_close now all i has to do is set the encoding to utf-8